# How to dynamically name index in Elasticsearch Date Name Index Processor?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to use Elasticseach Date Name Index Processor to make every log goes to the right index. That's easy.

My problem is that I need to name indices dynamically by using a field content but I don't know how to do it.

Below you have my pipeline. As you'll see I need to name indices by using a field called "deployment" (it is an existing field) but I don't know how.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/ixmd-date-index
{
  "description": "indexa la entrada de log en el índice correcto según el logdate",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "date_index_name" : {
        "field" : "logdate",
        "index_name_prefix" : "ixmd-{[fields.deployment]}-",
        "date_rounding" : "d",
        "date_formats": ["yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS", "ISO8601"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried several formats like "ixmd-%{[fields][deployment]}-", "ixmd-{fields.deployment}-",... but none works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `"index_name_prefix" : "ixmd-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"`

you can index your data by using the date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's not my problem. I need indices to be like "ixmd-server1-2018-09-10", "ixmd-testserver-2018-09-10",... where "server1" or "testserver" are in fields.deployment (a field created in Filebeat). So my problem is not using the date but using a custom text field inside my index name.

Comment: Ah ok sorry I misunderstood your question!  did you tried "ixmd-%{fieldName}"? for your example it's "ixmd-%{deployment}"

Comment: Yes. A lot of different combinations, but none works :(

Comment: Are you sure that your field exist? are you using only filebeat and not logstash to index your data ?

Comment: Yes. I've checked that "fields.deployment" exists in every log line (Filebeat introduce it). I am using just Filebeat. Trying to avoid Logstash to make final system lightweight. Thanks

Comment: Well it's strange what I suggest you to try is to do what you used to do but by using only "deployment" and not fields.deployment. I used already this syntax in logstash and it's works!

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

The right pipeline is:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/ixmd-date-index
{
  "description": "indexa la entrada de log en el índice correcto según el logdate",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "date_index_name" : {
        "field" : "logdate",
        "index_name_prefix" : "ixmd-{{ fields.deployment }}-",
        "date_rounding" : "d",
        "date_formats": ["yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So the right way to access to a field is by using {{ my_field }}. In my example, it is **{{ fields.deployment }}**, so the right way to define de index name prefix for me is:

```
"index_name_prefix" : "ixmd-{{ fields.deployment }}-"
```

and I'll get index named like "ixmd-server1-2018.09.12", "ixmd-server2-2018.09.12", and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To use index field value in index name dynamically you need to create a pipeline.

Example Elasticsearch index template:

```
{
"demo_template": {
    "order": 0,
    "index_patterns": [
        "demo*"
    ],
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "operator-id": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "interval-time": {
                "type": "date"
            }
        }
    },
  }
}
```

To create index name with format **demo-operator-id-date** you need to create a pipeline like this:

```
{
    "description": "version 1.0",
    "processors": [
    {
      "date_index_name": {
      "field": "interval-time",
      "index_name_prefix": "demo-{{{operator-id}}}-",
      "date_rounding": "w",
      "index_name_format": "yyyy.MM.dd"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Resulting index name will be **demo-456-2021.12.13**.